# Solspace User 3.3.5 compatible with EE 2.9?

Tags: solspace

I have one website which uses Solspace User version 3.3.5. The website is running ExpressionEngine version 2.2.2.  I was wondering if my 3.3.5 version of User will still work if I upgrade my ExpressionEngine webite to 2.9?

Answer (score 1):

Solspace have a handy version matrix which will help

http://www.solspace.com/software/compatibility

### update

You could risk it but I wouldn't. EE altered the form submission system pretty extensively in 2.8+. Take a local copy and try.

Comment: The matrix does not answer my question. I looked at it earlier today. It does not tell me if my 3.3.5 version of User will still work (not break apart) if I upgrade to EE 2.9. The matrix just tells me what can work in terms of the latest versions.

Comment: Givem changes under EE hood since 2.8 I'd wager youd have to upgrade. They introduced a new level of form submission.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for getting back to me. It's good to know. Will think about upgrading.

Comment: The compatibility matrix says that if you're on EE 2.9, you need **User 3.4.6 or higher** for User to work. In other words, User 3.3.5, being lower than 3.4.6 which is the minimum version to work with EE 2.9, would _not_ work correctly in EE 2.9.